# text {" "} added automatically when file saved

Tags: react-native, mobile

new to React native.

tried to update text in App.js file and save it. it thew following error

**Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.**

it also added  {" "} to the code...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwjnr.png)

can you please tell me what im doing wrong?
Regards
aq

i have tried everything. its some syntex error which i don't understand.

BUT why is it adding {" "} to the file?

---

Tried everything. remove space between one component and it adds {" "} in other places. the idea is not to compile the app...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you type a space between components.

For example:

```js
<View>
  <Text></Text> <StatusBar />
</View>
```

In this example, there is a space between `Text` and `StatusBar`, so if you format code, your code editor will convert this space to `{" "}`

**Solution**: Remove unnecessary space:

```js
<View>
  <Text></Text><StatusBar />
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, can you please tell me how to get rid of this shit. this is annoying. whenever i make some change and try to save it. react introduces these {" "}

Comment: @javatap This is very simple, please not put space between components in same line

Comment: the question is did they intentionally add this amazing feature in the compiler to confuse developers? or is it a bug which later became a feature because they coudl not resolve it?

Or maybe subscription fee for Trim function was too much react native?

Comment: I just test in `html` and your issue doesn't appear. So yes, maybe it is a feature of `react`

Comment: thanks, mate, as image above in my orignal post, I removed {" "} from one place and fixed neighboring components, and when I saved it showed {" "} in other places where it was not showing before... any idea??